# Does TFS 2015 Git provide a way to create pull request from a forked repo back to the original repo?

Tags: tfs-2015

I found a way to "[fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617620/forking-using-tfs-git)" a TFS 2015 Git repo.  But I don't see a way that a user on a fork could create a PR from their fork back to the original repo (upstream).  Can this be done?

Comment: I don't think it is supported. [This open suggestion on UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10967967-vsts-personal-git-repositories-for-forking) implicitly confirms that.

Comment: Thanks for the link!